# Maximum number of errors in BigQuery when uploading json files?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have some big json files in a Google Cloud Bucket. Very rarely, there is a “typo” in some random file, like a bracket missing or a value appearing as INT instead of STRING (quotation marks missing).

When I create a table in BigQuery using such a file, it throws errors and the process is ended. How could I set a maximum number of errors?

I know this is possible when working with `.csv`. I know there is a parameter for json but not when working with the GUI?

Is this possible in the GUI? If not, how do I do it in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a parameter in BigQuery GUI to set the maximum number of errors during the table creation from the JSON file from Google Cloud Storage.

When you have the "Create table" dialog in BigQuery GUI, go to the "Advanced options" section and click on it. You'll find the field "Number of errors allowed" there.

I tried to upload the following JSON file (note the missing quote before the "Dddd")

```
{ "id": 1, "name" : "Aaaa" }
{ "id": 2, "name" : "Bbbb" }
{ "id": 3, "name" : "Cccc" }
{ "id": 4, "name" : Dddd" }
```

I had configured the "Create table" in the following way:
[image]

The table was created and three records were there (with id 1, 2 and 3).